# How to get rid of this: "[-f: command not found" in terminal?

Tags: bash, shell

This message appears above the command line when I start the terminal.
How to get rid of that?
There is no difference which terminal to use. It appears either in xfce4-terminal or xterm

`[-f: command not found 
  username@linux:~>`

Comment: Check your `~/.bash*` and `~/.profile*` files. And please don't post text as a picture, just use the format functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in your `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bashrc` (et al) for any line containing `[-f`, and change it to `[ -f`.