# Command '“export' not found when starting a terminal app in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Every time I start my terminal I get this message; how to get rid of it?

```
Command '“export' not found, did you mean:
  command 'mexport' from deb mblaze (0.6-1)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: ... and `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 6):

I wondered why your machine did not have the `export` command... then I noticed that your error message actually says `“export`. Your post was not code-formatted at first so the quotation mark was hard to spot.

You have a typo in your `~/.bashrc` or your  `~/.bash_profile` file: `“export` where it should be `export` or `"export`.  Fix it and the error should be gone.

Similar questions:

- [How to get rid of this: "[-f: command not found" in terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371141/how-to-get-rid-of-this-f-command-not-found-in-terminal)
- [How to avoid "bash: q: command not found" every time I 'su'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332271/how-to-avoid-bash-q-command-not-found-every-time-i-su)

---

Note: The shape of the quotation marks - `“` instead of `"` - tells me that you probably copy-pasted the line from some document or webpage, or you edited the file with a word processor that adds fancy quotes, as @Kusalananda said in the comments.
 You have always to be careful about the formatting, as word processors often perform "smart" character substitution, mangling your code in the process; an infamous example is `--someoption` being transformed into `—someoption` (the two hyphens having been replaced with a mdash).

Comment: Note `“`, not `"`, at the start of that command. It could be that they've edited the file with a word processor or on a system that automatically inserts "fancy" quotes.